# href in PHP to redirect to further information

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I have a link next to my product at the moment, the link will take the user to a page with more information about the product at hand stored in the database.
I don't want to have a different link, so the product itself is the link.

**this is the code I have at the moment where the link is next to the product.**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
    ?>
    <td><a href="list_item.php?id=<?php echo $row['Band_id'] ?>">view Information</a></td>
    <?php 
    echo "</td>";
}
```

Ok so what im trying to get is the link "view information" to be  echo "".$row['Name']."";

so echo "".$row['Name'].""; is the link.

**Further explanation**

if you go to the link http://stuweb.cms.gre.ac.uk/~ob219/addband/mysql_con_links.php

what i what is the band name to be the link and not have a anoutherlink for more information

Comment: what is the error you are having?

Comment: I'm not sure I can work out what your question is. Perhaps try rephrasing or explaining in more detail?

Comment: sory guys have added more to my question to explain better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="list_item.php?id=<?php echo $row['Band_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

Then you can remove `<th>More Infomation</th>`.

Basically, you end up with a table like this:

```
+-------------+
|  Band Name  |
+-------------+
|  Killer     |
+-------------+
```

In which 'Killer' is the actual link to the information page.

Comment: Brilliant, has worked perfect. thank you turns out i was on the right path before but i misses the ?php when i tried it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
<td><a href="list_item.php?id=<?php echo $row['Band_id'] ?>">view Information</a></td>
```

with:

```
<td><a href="list_item.php?id=<?php echo {$row['Band_id']} ?>">view Information</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you will need to remove **view information** and put the php echo there instead like:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><a href='list_item.php?id=".$row['Band_id'].">".$row['Name']."</a></td>";
}
```

Try this.

Comment: Problem is i have tried this and it just shows the code as the string rather than the name.